# How to shuffle an array inside a symfony controller?

Tags: arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need a page that shows 20 random pics from the database, but since using the RAND() function is not recommended for large tables, i'm just trying to pic 20 random values from the array inside the controller.

This is the working code that returns all images

```
/**
*@Route("/world/shuffle")
*/
public function shufflepageAction()
{ 
    $images = $this->get('doctrine')->getRepository('GabrielUploadBundle:Image')->findAll();

    return $this->render('GabrielLayoutBundle:Worldpage:shuffle.html.twig',array('images'=>$images));
}
```

Now I need to pick 20 results and shuffle them (doesn't work)

```
    /**
    *@Route("/world/shuffle")
    */
    public function shufflepageAction()
    { 
        $images = $this->get('doctrine')->getRepository('GabrielUploadBundle:Image')->findAll();
        $simages = array_rand($images,20); //randomize
        return $this->render('GabrielLayoutBundle:Worldpage:shuffle.html.twig',array('images'=>$simages));
    }
}
```

it throws this error for some reason

> Impossible to access an attribute ("upvotes") on a integer variable
>   ("1") in GabrielLayoutBundle:Worldpage:shuffle.html.twig at line 20

(on line 20 I loop through the returned "images" array using a for loop on twig)

//for loop:

```
   {% for image in images %} 
       // findstuff
   {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please provide the code corresponding to your for loop in your twig template.

Answer (score 2):

Laurent Wartel is correct - you are using an incorrect function. Try [`shuffle`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) to randomise an array's contents instead. For example:

```
$a = range(1, 10);
shuffle($a);
print_r($a);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 9
    [3] => 5
    [4] => 8
    [5] => 7
    [6] => 2
    [7] => 6
    [8] => 10
    [9] => 1
)
```

Comment: tried but shuffle returns true or false instead of the associative array

Comment: Hi @user3531149 - `shuffle()` accepts a reference to an array, and shuffles it 'in-place'. It doesn't return a new array, just an indication of success/failure. I updated my answer there with an example. Live example here: https://eval.in/137361

Answer (score 1):

From [PHP: array_rand](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) :

> When picking only one entry, array_rand() returns the key for a random entry. Otherwise, an array of keys for the random entries is returned. This is done so that random keys can be picked from the array as well as random values. Trying to pick more elements than there are in the array will result in an E_WARNING level error, and NULL will be returned.

The `$simages` variable is an array containing random **keys**. So you need to give the `$images` variable to the view, and then do something like :

```
{% for key in simages %}
    {{ images[key].upvotes }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all calling findAll on big table is bad idea.

If you don't want to use RAND() then consider generating 20 random unique primary keys array and then executing query with

```
$queryBuilder->andWhere('r.id IN (:ids)')
          ->setParameter('ids', $ids);
```

where

```
$ids = array(213, 2131, 33, 982, ...);
```

Comment: Yes. Using `findAll()` to subsequently pick a subset of display items is definitely best avoided and not very scalable.

Comment: thanks, can I optimize this findAll() query using the current solution?
(check answer "This seems to do the job...")

Comment: No, you can't optimize. In findAll you simple fetch all rows from database and then operate on PHP array. This is a performance and resource killer. You shouldn't fetch all rows when you only need 20.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the job, now I only need to limit the results

```
/**
*@Route("/world/shuffle",name="world-shuffle")
*/
public function shufflepageAction()
{ 

    function shuffle_assoc($array)
    {
        // Initialize
            $shuffled_array = array();

        // Get array's keys and shuffle them.
            $shuffled_keys = array_keys($array);
            shuffle($shuffled_keys);

        // Create same array, but in shuffled order.
            foreach ( $shuffled_keys AS $shuffled_key ) 
            {
                $shuffled_array[  $shuffled_key  ] = $array[  $shuffled_key  ];
            } 
        // Return
            return $shuffled_array;
    }

    $images = $this->get('doctrine')->getRepository('GabrielUploadBundle:Image')->findAll();
    $simages = shuffle_assoc($images); //randomize
    //ladybug_dump($simages);
    //$this->get('ladybug')->log($simages);
    return $this->render('GabrielLayoutBundle:Worldpage:shuffle.html.twig',array('images'=>$simages));
}
```